# getting error "name 'y_test' is not defined"

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

New to machine learning
I am trying to figure out the `accuracy score` of a linear model using `accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred)`.both the variables are defined. But getting error

> 'name 'y_test' is not defined'.

Can anyone help me with this?
variables are defined like this:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, random_state=123)
y_pred = linreg.predict(X_test)
```

detailed error message..
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
      1 #for checking the accuracy and details
      2 from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
----> 3 accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred)

NameError: name 'y_test' is not defined

Keeping code here...

```
#creating a function for models
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import metrics
#function
def train_test_rmse(x,y):
    x = Iris_data[x]
    y = Iris_data[y]
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.2,random_state=123)
    linreg = LinearRegression()
    linreg.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = linreg.predict(X_test)
    return np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))

print(train_test_rmse(['Sepal.Length'],['Sepal.Width']))
print(train_test_rmse(['Petal.Length'],['Sepal.Width']))
print(train_test_rmse(['Sepal.Length'],['Petal.Width']))
print(train_test_rmse(['Petal.Length'],['Petal.Width'])) #this one has least rmse
print(train_test_rmse(['Sepal.Width'],['Sepal.Length']))
print(train_test_rmse(['Petal.Width'],['Sepal.Width']))

#for checking the accuracy and details
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred)
```

Comment: provide full error message and some sample data.

Comment: @Akhsay: it is the iris data .                                                                  NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-ba6c19ddde2a> in <module>()
      1 #for checking the accuracy and details
      2 from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
----> 3 accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred)

NameError: name 'y_test' is not defined

Comment: post that in your question(by editing your question) not in comment. It would easier to understand. If you are using jupyter notebook, restart your kernel and try running the code again.

Comment: thanks, Akshay, I have updated my question. refreshed and  restarted the kernel but same error

Comment: I think you are missing `test_size` parameter in your `train_test_split`. Use `X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=123)`

Comment: added test size but same error.

Comment: You need to show more code then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.2,random_state=123)
```

inside the `train_test_rmse()` function. That's why scope of these variable (`y_test` and `y_pred`) are inside the function only.

They can not be used outside the function.

Use below code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

#function
def train_test_rmse(x,y):
    x = Iris_data[x]
    y = Iris_data[y]
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.2,random_state=123)
    linreg = LinearRegression()
    linreg.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = linreg.predict(X_test)
    print(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))  # or you can save it in variable and return it 
    return np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))
```